Unable to show custom tooltip renderer in Integrated Ag-Charts
I'm trying to change the default value of my tooltip content following the documentation of Ag-Charts.
Checking doc:
    tooltip: {
    renderer: function ({ datum, xKey, yKey }) {
        return {
            content: datum[yKey].toFixed(0),
            title: datum[xKey]
        };
    },
},

They made Object Destructuring from renderer(params) to get {datum, xKey, yKey}, and made a Objet access to vinculate xKey and yKey by datum.
I did something similar and I'm getting "R$ undefined" when trying to edit datum[xKey] return, but if I just return raw, my data is displayed:
    tooltip: {
          enabled: true,
          renderer({ datum, xKey, yKey }) {
            console.log('datum data: ', datum);
            return {
              title: datum[yKey],
              content: `${datum[yKey].toLocaleString('pt-BR', {
                style: 'currency',
                currency: 'BRL'
              })}`
            };
          }
        }


There's something I can do or I'm doing the wrong way?
My console log from datum returns:
datum data: 
{
    "__children": [
        {
            "salesOrders.paymentMethodName": "Cartão de Crédito",
            "salesOrders.avgWithDiscounts": 93.34
        },
        {
            "salesOrders.paymentMethodName": "Cartão de Crédito",
            "salesOrders.avgWithDiscounts": 40
        },
    ],
    "salesOrders.paymentMethodName": "Cartão de Crédito",
    "salesOrders.avgWithDiscounts": 57021.469714285704
}

children is unit data, but I make a sum function to show all data:aggFunc: 'sum', any advice in this one?

can you add a small sample codesandbox or plunkr? it will be easier to understand the issue and help you that way

@sandeepjoshi I'll try to do that since I have massive data before going to charts.

just add the data which you are using for tooltip rendering. I am suspecting its related to either data or the way it is getting formatted. still would be better to look at small working code

I'm using "salesOrders.paymentMethodName": "Cartão de Crédito" and     "salesOrders.avgWithDiscounts": 57021.469714285704, ag-charts don't use formated values from valueFormatter or CellRenderer, but raw value linked to columns
